# How do I get a DisconnectEvent on a force kill on Asterisk PBX

Tags: java, asterisk, disconnect

I have a Java application that listens to Asterisk events from the AMI. Whenever the Asterisk PBX is down, I would want the AMI event listener to tell me if it has disconnected. Thankfully, a `DisconnectEvent` is already built in so whenever I do a `service asterisk stop`, my Java app gets notified about Asterisk going down.

However, when I do a `kill -9 <asterisk_pid>`, it doesn't send anymore events -- and it's obvious why. Is there anyway I can still get the `DisconnectEvent` (or something else similar) in this scenario?

The reason why I need this behavior is because when Asterisk is down, I display an error on my Java app saying "Asterisk is down".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"kill -9" mean  kill imidiate, do not wait program send any handler.

So answer is : you can't